# Pandas interpretes string as scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas

When I create a dataframe from a excel file, it has a string value '2098E10'.
But pandas interpret the letter E on string as scientific notation converting the value to 20980000000000.
How can I suppress this panda's behavior to keep the values '2098E10' as string?

I have tried to convert the values to string, but the value will be '20980000000000'.

Comment: Specify the `dtype` when using `read_excel`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pandas.read_csv` with the correct `dtype` argument (`str` for you), e.g.

```
pd.read_csv('data/data_7.csv',
                 dtype={
                     'Name': str,
                     'Grade': int
                 })
```

Hint taken from [this blog post #5](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-pandas-read-csv-you-should-know-to-speed-up-your-data-analysis-1e16fe1039f3).